# Java: Converting RSS feed to HTML

Tags: java, xml, xslt, rss

I am currently doing a java project where I get a url which contains an RSS feed, and am required to convert that RSS feed into HTML. So I have done a bit of research and managed to convert it into XML, so I can convert it to HTML with XSLT. However, that process requires a XSL file, which I have no idea how to get/ create. How would I go about attempting this problem? I cannot hard code it, as the resource url may change the events/news on the site and therefore effect my output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSS feeds came in two formats: [RSS 2.0](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html) and [ATOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29) - depending on which kind do you want/need to handle you'll need different XSLT.

This is a very simple XSLT that convert a RSS 2.0 feed into a HTML page:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()"></xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <h2>
      <a href="{link}">
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
      </a>
    </h2>
    <p>
      <xsl:value-of select="description" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/rss/channel">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </title>
      </head>
    </html>
    <body>
      <h1>
        <a href="{link}">
          <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </a>
      </h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...and this is the same for a ATOM feed:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()"></xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="atom:entry">
    <h2>
      <a href="{atom:link/@href}">
        <xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/>
      </a>
    </h2>
    <p>
      <xsl:value-of select="atom:summary"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/atom:feed">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/>
        </title>
      </head>
    </html>
    <body>
      <h1>
        <a href="{atom:link/@href}">
          <xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/>
        </a>
      </h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you very much, this really helped. I am still a little unsure on how to create my own XSL file for this RSS feed. How do I include the the attributes like the pubDate etc.?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
 <title>Events from Computer Science:other_events</title>
    <link>http://www.auckland.ac.nz</link>
    <description>Latest events from Computer Science:other_events</description>
    <language>en-nz</language>
    <pubDate>Thu Sep 11 00:00:00 NZST 3913</pubDate>
    <lastBuildDate>Wed, 11 Sep 2013 11:35:37 +1200</lastBuildDate>
    <copyright>The University of Auckland</copyright>
 <category>other_events</category>

Comment: <item><title><![CDATA[Computer Science research hors d’oeuvres]]></title><link>http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz:80/uoa/home/template/event_item.jsp?cid=581187</link><description><![CDATA[Thinking about doing some postgraduate research? Come and hear our staff members talk about what inspires and excites them - their research.
11 September 2013
]]></description><pubDate>Wed, 11 Sep 2013 13:00:00 +1200</pubDate><endDate>Wed, 25 Sep 2013 14:00:00 +1200</endDate></item>
</channel>
</rss>